# How to add a header row to a GridView table in VB.NET?

Tags: html, vb.net

```html
<asp:GridView ID="MemberTable" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" 
    EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Forename" SortExpression="Forename" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="EmailAddress" SortExpression="EmailAddress" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserType" HeaderText="UserType" SortExpression="UserType" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
</asp:GridView>
```

[image: Table]

How can I add a single cell header row on the very top of this table? (preferably using only tags)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You already have a header row - do you need another one above it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridViews don't have as much control over table headers and footers or th cells as you would want.

However, you say you want a "single cell header row", which sounds like you're looking for a caption. That's possible; see MSDN [GridView.Caption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.caption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```html
<asp:GridView (...) Caption="Hello Table!" CaptionAlign="Left">
```

And with a bit of css styling, you can make the caption look just like a table row.

```css
<style type="text/css">
  caption {background-color:#E3EAEB; padding:4px}
</style>
```

[image]